# How do I maintain a clean system compiling package not in the main channel in Nixos?

Tags: compiling, nixos, nix

I wish to install a program that is not available through the main channel in Nixos. How do I ensure that the proper dependencies will be installed, ideally in a way that is described in a configuration file that can be replicated as is with the rest of programs installed with nix?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply `nix-env -f /path/to/custom/nixpkgs -iA your-package`.

Almost all dependencies in nixpkgs are pure, so the various versions on your system "don't affect each other". You can then `nix-copy-closure` that package to other machines, etc.